# How can some enzymes work faster than the diffusion rates of the reactants allow?

Tags: catalysis, enzyme-kinetics

Quoting Wikipedia: ["Some enzymes operate with kinetics which are faster than diffusion rates, which would seem to be impossible."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_limited_enzyme#Mechanism) Which are those enzymes and how can they be so fast?

One example is catalase in which peroxide is catalyzed faster than the diffusion rate of peroxide allows. Lionel Milgrom discusses this case in [Water Journal no. 7](https://www.waterjournal.org/volume-7/milgrom).

Comment: It doesn't work faster than diffusion. It's diffusion-limited. However, if diffusion rates were faster, the enzyme would also work faster. The bottom line is that you are rate-limited by diffusion in solution.

Answer (score 5):

The conceptually easiest case is that of a positively charged active site with a negatively charged substrate. The substrate (i.e. reactant) enters the active site with kinetics that are faster than diffusion because there is a long-range electrostatic interaction.

Catalase works near the diffusion limit. The document the OP cites is a hypothesis, without experimental data. It suggests that catalase acts at a distance to catalyze reactions outside of its active site. I would not worry about this hypothesis until there is some experimental evidence supporting it.

Wikipedia has a list of 9 examples of [diffusion limited enzymes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion_limited_enzyme#Examples):

> Acetylcholinesterase
>
> β-lactamase
>
> Catalase
>
> Carbonic anhydrase
>
> Carbon monoxide dehydrogenase
>
> Cytochrome c peroxidase
>
> Fumarase
>
> Superoxide dismutase
>
> Triosephosphate isomerase

Some of them have neutral substrates, so the electrostatic attraction would not apply to them. There are other hypothetical mechanisms, though, like weak binding sites on the surface of the enzyme that increase the local concentration of substrate, for example.

Comment: I think enzyme kinetics in the case of the OP would refer to overall turnover rate, not just to binding rate. So whatever the mechanism of association, what's fast is the combination of binding, reaction in the active site, and release.

Comment: @BuckThorn If it is diffusion-limited, the binding step is limiting. If it is faster than the theoretical diffusion limit, the puzzling thing is how it can bind faster than that limit. It is amazing in any case that practically every binding event leads to a reaction, very different from what happens in the absence of a catalyst.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding enzymes seemingly beating the diffusion limit,
there is an additional factor to consider, and that is stirring!

Can enzymes stir a solution?

The answer at first sight is no, but then enzymes are large, complex and may have inward and outward channels. In cases were the active site design is such, the substrate may be forced to enter from one side to form a productive complex, be converted and leave on a different side, thus producing a flow. If the reaction free energy is favorable and if oriented properly, that flow would literally impulse the protein molecule in some direction and could stir the solution nearby.
In catalases, the active site design creates a bottleneck and the site seems designed to filter out water at the inward channel, leave peroxide in, and the reaction's free energy change is large and negative (Dominguez et al., 2010 [10.1016/j.abb.2010.05.017](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.abb.2010.05.017)). In theory, this may create a net flow and propel the protein in some direction.

The effect however, does not seem to have been tested experimentally.

Comment: Are there means to detect such motion in the small volume that they would occur in?

Comment: May be difficult to see it in a single-molecule experiment. However, you could place a small drop of concentrated enzyme in an agar plate, containing a small concentration of hydrogen peroxide. Then compare the rate of protein diffusion in the plate, against, the diffusion of a protein of similar size, with no catalase activity (i.e. BSA).  It might be possible to see a systematic reproducible difference, because the enzyme would consume the local peroxide and a gradient would be created. The difficult part is to measure protein diffusion.

Answer (score 1):

May be difficult to see it in a single-molecule experiment. However, you could place a small drop of concentrated enzyme in an agar plate, containing a small concentration of hydrogen peroxide. Then compare the rate of protein diffusion in the plate, against, the diffusion of a protein of similar size, with no catalase activity (i.e. BSA). It might be possible to see a systematic reproducible difference, because the enzyme would consume the local peroxide and a gradient would be created.
The difficult part is to measure protein diffusion. You could stain the agar with coomasie blue, but that would mean a lot a agar replicates. A fluorescent catalase may help, but the label would have to withstand peroxidation (most probes would loose their flourescence). That is the part I have not figured out how to tackle-Any ideas?